# Windows Batch to copy logs working in Windows 7 but not in Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
::Destination folder, where log files compressed in zip will be copied
SET DestinationDir=c:\temp\ZodiacLogs

SET DATE="%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%"
set /p DATE_FROM="Pls Enter From DATE (MM/DD/yyyy):- "
set /p DATE_TO="Pls Enter To Date(MM/DD/yyyy) :- "
set fdate=%date_from:~0,2%%date_from:~3,2%%date_from:~6,4%-%date_to:~0,2%%date_to:~3,2%%date_to:~6,4%
set time=%time::=%

ECHO Starting to copy the log files ......

PUSHD \\NGTSVR14\work

:: Advice Log
ECHO Copying Advice logs ... 
> nul forfiles /P \Advice\LogFile /s /D +%DATE_FROM% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%DATE_TO% && > con (cmd /c xcopy /S /Y /F @path %DestinationDir%\ops_logs_%fdate%\%computername%\Advice\)"

:: Crane Schedule server logs
ECHO Copying Workflow server logs ...
> nul forfiles /P \CraneScheduleServer\LogFile /D +%DATE_FROM% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%DATE_TO% && > con (cmd /c xcopy /S /Y @path %DestinationDir%\ops_logs_%fdate%\%computername%\CraneScheduleServer\)"


POPD

:: Below commands will Zip the folder

ECHO Zipping...

c:
cd C:\temp\ZodiacLogs

for /d %%X in (*ops*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "ops_logs_%fdate%_%time%.zip" "%%X\"
for /d %%X in (*ops*) do RMDIR "%%X" /S /Q

pause
```

This above batch I'm using to copy logs from a server to a Windows 10 client,but it is not copying any files. From Windows 7 client it is working fine. Please help to resolve

Comment: Well, this is not a code review and fixation site! Please describe precisely what your script is supposed to do and what it actually does. Also consider to post it on [StackOverflow](https://stackovervlow.com) and to delete it here. Hint: `%date%` and `%time%` are locale-dependent...

Comment: Hi, The script suppose to run on a windows 10 client machine, and it is copying logs from a server to client machine between the date given by user.

Comment: Is it giving you any errors? If the console just closes right away, run this manually in the console instead of double clicking the batch file.

Comment: it resolved.. I just removed "> nul" before forfiles command.